# Is there any way to hide/customize "Can’t access your account?" link in Azure AD login page?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We are using free edition of Azure account and trying to hide/customize "Can’t access your account?" link in Azure AD that's default login page as self service password reset(SSPR) feature is supported using Basic or Premium edition.

If we can hide/customize the link url that will be helpful.

Any help or hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't currently hide this.